# When try to mvn clean install -> an error package does not exist appear

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, maven-plugin, maven-compiler-plugin

I have been trying to do: `mvn clean install` on a project which depends on external jar, but got:

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project automation-service: Compilation failure: Compilation failure:
[ERROR] /C:/Checkouts/Release-4.0/test-service-intelligence/service-automation-service/src/test/java/com/company/automation/steps/BasicsSteps.java:[16,53] package com.company.service.automation.databaseaccess does not exist
/C:/Checkouts/Release-4.0/test-service-intelligence/service-automation-service/src/test/java/com/company/automation/steps/BasicsSteps.java:[43,13] cannot find symbol
[ERROR]   symbol:   class IdentifierIndexRepository
```

and weirdly this was successfully executed on my colleagues MAC (although he is using completely different IDE, tools and stuff. For example he is using X-Code IDE, ZULU 8 JDK, Maven 3.5). Firstly I though it is a JDK problem and switch the JDK as the same as his: ZULU 8, then I tried his version of Apache Maven and downgraded from 3.6 to 3.5. And finally I switched from Intelij Idea to Eclipse out of desperation -> nothing helps me.
It seems that the missing package is from an external dependency jar which is supplied successfully - I can see it in the External libraries, also there is no signs for unresolved dependencies before trying to `mvn clean install` (`mvn clean compile` pass successfully)

the dependency in the POM is declared like that:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.company.da.fid.resolve</groupId>
  <artifactId>automation-database-access</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <classifier>jar-with-dependencies</classifier>
</dependency>
```

and maven-compiler-plugin like that:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.1</version>
    <configuration>
      <source>8</source>
      <target>8</target>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

The dependency .jar file consists his owns dependencies in him.

Anyone have an idea or clue what possibly could happen to me ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using a `jar-with-dependencies` as dependency is usually discouraged.

Comment: @JFabianMeier, please advice what are my other options besides jar-with-dependencies ? I am eager to re-work this .jar if needed.

Comment: A `jar-with-dependencies` is usually used if you want to run the JAR from command line (executable JAR, fat JAR). For a dependency, you just take the "usual" JAR. Maven resolves transitive dependencies automatically, so you there is no need to package all the dependencies into one JAR.

Comment: @AngelElenkov any solution please? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

From the error log it shows that you are missing the dependency `com.company...`. And it seems to me that it is a custom library you are using. If you have the source code, do `clean install` of the lib and then on the main project.

This may occur if you have a corrupt package(of the dependency) locally. To check this go to **.m2** folder and verify that you have it, if so delete and try to run `clean install` again.

Comment: The dependency is a custom library (the jar file) it is correctly located in my local m2 repository and it is downloaded from there successfully. I have tried to delete and re-install many times, alas with no success.

Comment: @AngelElenkov any solution please? I am facing the same issue.